# Names of extended family members

Tags: word-choice, mandarin

In 闽南话/Hokkien (and 启海话, and possibly all dialects) when we call our uncles and aunties we call them by the order of their age and whether they're on our father's or mother's sides, and the wives/husbands of those people.

As some examples, this is what it would be like in Hokkien:

```
Tua pei & Tua mm (father's eldest brother and his wife)
Di chek & Di chim (father's 2nd brother and his wife)
Saa chek & Saa chim (father's 3rd brother and his wife)
Bay chek & Bay chim (father's youngest brother and his wife)

Tua ku & Tua kim (mother's eldest brother and his wife)
Di ku & Di kim (mother's 2nd brother and his wife)
Saa ku & Saa kim (mother's 3rd brother and his wife)
Bay ku & Bay kim (mother's youngest brother and his wife)
```

Unfortunately, all I can find in Mandarin is the following:

```
伯父 (father's elder brother) & 大妈 (his wife)
叔父 (father's younger brother) & 婶婶 (his wife)

舅舅 (mother's brother) & 舅妈 (his wife)
```

Is that all the granularity required in Mandarin, or are there more specifics, just hiding where I can't find it? I want to know what the Mandarin equivalents are, or if that's all I need to say.

A list of these somewhere would be great.

Comment: Please check out this answer: http://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/5951/2583

Comment: Have a look at http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=nCFRoILS1jY  on my phone so excuse the mobile link

Comment: @50-3 wow. Just wow.

Comment: I know right? Also putting a close vote in as asking for learning resource and too broad. Sorry

Comment: Voting to close as it is not clear what you are asking. If you understand Hokkien, then translating it to Mandarin should be a piece of cake. Example "tua" is 大, "bay" means last, etc.

Comment: Is there any reason why you romanised the Hokkien section? Wouldn't it just be blatantly obvious, if you had written everything in Chinese characters?

Comment: @deutschZuid because I only know how to speak Hokkien ... if I could write it and it was blatantly obvious, I wouldn't need to ask this question ..

Answer (score 3):

```
Tua pei & Tua mm 大伯 & 大伯母
di chek &  di chim  二叔 & 二婶 (二叔母)
Saa chek & Saa chim 三叔 & 三婶 (三叔母)
Bay chek & Bay chim 小叔 & 小婶 (小叔母)

Tua ku & Tua kim  大舅 & 大舅母
Di ku & Di kim    二舅 & 二舅母
Saa ku & Saa kim  三舅 & 三舅母
Bay ku & Bay kim  小舅 & 小舅母
```

You probably can see the pattern now

In chinese, if the uncle is the brother who is elder than your father, you need to call him 伯伯(pei in hokkien), if younger than your father is called 叔叔（ chek in hokkien).

for mother's brother side, there is no such difference like this

---

For father's sisters(regardless elder or younger than father), we call 姑姑

```
eldest sister & husband 大姑 & 大姑丈
2nd sis & husband 二姑 & 二姑丈
3rd sis & husband 三姑 & 三姑丈
youngest sis & husband 小姑 & 小姑丈
```

For mother's sisters(regardless elder or younger than father), we call 姨姨

```
eldest sister & husband 大姨 & 大姨丈
2nd sis & husband 二姨 & 二姨丈
3rd sis & husband 三姨 & 三姨丈
youngest sis & husband 小姨 & 小姨丈
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you have a corresponding list for sisters on either side and their husbands?

Comment: added in the answers

Comment: btw, 婶婶 can be refer as 叔母 as well

Comment: And mother's brothers + their wives are all just 舅舅 (mother's brother) & 舅妈 (his wife)?

Comment: yup. that's correct

Answer (score 3):

Family Members in Mandarin

```
father: 爸 ba4 /爸爸 ba4 ba/爹 die1/爹爹 die1 die/父 fu4/父亲 fu4 qin
mother: 妈 ma1/妈妈 ma1 ma/娘 niang2/母 mu3/母亲 mu3 qin
son: 儿子 er2 zi
daughter: 女儿 nv3 er2
older brother: 哥 ge1/哥哥 ge1 ge/兄 xiong1/兄长 xiong1 zhang3
younger bother: 弟 di4/弟弟 di4 di/兄弟 xiong1 di4
older sister: 姐 jie3/姐姐 jie3 jie/姊 zi3/姊姊zi3 zi
younger sister: 妹 mei4/妹妹 mei4 mei

husband: 夫 fu1/丈夫 zhang4 fu/老公 lao3 gong1/先生 xian1 sheng
wife: 妻 qi1/妻子 qi1 zi/老婆 lao3 po2/太太 tai4 tai/媳妇 xi2 fu4/内人 nei4 ren

son’s wife: 儿媳 er2 xi2/儿媳妇 er2 xi2 fu4
son’s wife’s dad: 亲家公 qing4 jia1 gong1
son’s wife’s mom: 亲家母 qing4 jia1 mu4
son’s son: 孙子 sun1 zi
son’s daughter: 孙女 sun1 nv3

daughter’s husband: 婿 xu4/女婿 nv3 xu4
daughter’s husband’s dad: 亲家公 qing4 jia1 gong1
daughter’s husband’s mom: 亲家母 qing4 jia1 mu4
daughter’s son: 外孙 wai4 sun1
daughter’s daughter: 外孙女 wai4 sun1 nv3

older brother’s wife: 嫂子 sao3 zi
younger bother’s wife: 弟妹 di4 mei4/弟媳 di4 xi2/弟媳妇 di4 xi2 fu4
brother’s son: 侄 zhi2/侄子 zhi2 zi
brother’s daughter: 侄女 zhi2 nv3
older sister’s husband: 姐夫 jie3 fu
younger sister’s husband: 妹夫 mei4 fu
sister’s son: 外甥 wai4 sheng
sister’s daughter: 外甥女 wai4 sheng1 nv3

father’s dad: 爷 ye2/爷爷 ye2 ye/祖父 zu3 fu4
father’s mom: 奶 nai3/奶奶 nai3 nai/祖母 zu3 mu3
father’s older brother: 伯 bo2/伯伯 bo2 bo/伯父 bo2 fu4/大爷 da4 ye
father’s older brother’s wife: 伯母 bo2 mu3/大娘 da4 niang2
father’s younger brother: 叔 shu1/叔叔 shu1 shu/叔父 shu1 fu4
father’s younger brother’ wife: 婶 shen3/婶子 shen3 zi/婶婶 shen3 shen
father’s brother’s son (older than me): 堂兄 tang2 xiong1
father’s brother’s son (younger than me): 堂弟 tang2 di4
father’s brother’s daughter (older than me): 堂姐 tang2 jie3
father’s brother’s daughter (younger than me): 堂妹 tang2 mei4
father’s sister: 姑 gu1/姑姑 gu1 gu/姑母 gu1 mu3/姑妈 gu1 ma1
father’s sister’s husband: 姑父 gu1 fu4
father’s sister’s son (older than me): 表哥biao3 ge1/表兄 biao3 xiong1
father’s sister’s son (younger than me): 表弟 biao3 di4
father’s sister’s daughter (older than me): 表姐 biao3 jie3
father’s sister’s daughter (younger than me): 表妹 biao3 mei4

mother’s dad: 姥爷 lao3 ye/外公 wai4 gong1/外祖父 wai4 zu3 fu4
mother’s mom: 姥 lao3/姥姥 lao3 lao/外婆 wai4 po2/外祖母 wai4 zu3 mu3
mother’s brother: 舅 jiu4/舅舅 jiu4 jiu/舅父 jiu4 fu4
mother’s brother’s wife: 舅母 jiu4 mu3/舅妈 jiu4 ma1
mother’s brother’s son (older than me): 表哥biao3 ge1/表兄 biao3 xiong1
mother’s brother’s son (younger than me): 表弟 biao3 di4
mother’s brother’s daughter (older than me): 表姐 biao3 jie3
mother’s brother’s daughter (younger than me): 表妹 biao3 mei4
mother’s sister: 姨 yi2/姨妈 yi2 ma1/姨母yi2 mu3
mother’s sister’s husband: 姨父 yi2 fu4
mother’s sister’s son (older than me): 表哥biao3 ge1/表兄 biao3 xiong1
mother’s sister’s son (younger than me): 表弟 biao3 di4
mother’s sister’s daughter (older than me): 表姐 biao3 jie3
mother’s sister’s daughter (younger than me): 表妹 biao3 mei4

husband’s dad: 公公 gong1 gong
husband’s mom: 婆婆 po2 po
husband’s older brother: 大伯哥 da4 bai1 ge1/大伯子 da4 bai1 zi
husband’s older brother’s wife: 嫂子sao3 zi
husband’s younger brother: 小叔 xiao3 shu1/小叔子 xiao3 shou1 zi
husband’s younger brother’s wife: 弟妹 di4 mei4/弟媳 di4 xi2/弟媳妇 di4 xi2 fu4
husband’s brother’ son: 侄子 nei4 zi
husband’s brother’ daughter: 侄女 zhi2 nv3
husband’s older sister: 大姑子 da4 gu1 zi/大姑姐 da4 gu1 jie3
husband’s older sister’s husband: 姐夫 jie3 fu
husband’s younger sister: 小姑子 xiao3 gu1 zi
husband’s younger sister’s husband: 妹夫 mei4 fu
husband’s sister’s son: 外甥 wai4 sheng
husband’s sister’s daughter: 外甥 wai4 sheng

wife’s dad: 丈人 zhang4 ren/老丈人 lao3 zhang4 ren/岳父 yue4 fu4
wife’s mom: 丈母娘 zhang4 mu3 niang2/岳母 yue4 mu3
wife’s older brother: 大舅哥 da4 jiu4 ge1/内兄 nei4 xiong1
wife’s older brother’s wife: 大舅嫂 da4 jiu4 sao3
wife’s younger brother: 小舅子 xiao3 jiu4 zi/内弟 nei4 di4
wife’s younger brother’s wife: 弟妹 di4 mei4/弟媳 di4 xi2/弟媳妇 di4 xi2 fu4
wife’s brother’ son: 内侄 nei4 zhi2
wife’s brother’ daughter: 内侄女 nei4 zhi2 nv3
wife’s older sister: 大姨子 da4 yi2 zi/大姨姐 da4 yi2 jie3
wife’s older sister’ husband: 姐夫 jie3 fu
wife’s younger sister: 小姨子 xiao3 yi2 zi
wife’s younger sister’s husband: 妹夫 mei4 fu
wife’s sister’s son: 外甥 wai4 sheng
wife’s sister’s daughter: 外甥女 wai4 sheng1 nv3
```

Answer (score 0):

Numbers.

like: 李二婶 would be `[the Li family's] second eldest son's wife`

Maybe this is Topolectical aswell though, but it's in the numbers...

Comment: Thanks, so if it's your 2nd uncle's wife, would just say to her on greeting, "二婶好!" is that right?

Comment: Yeah, but I'm sure it will depend on the specific place -- every place will most likely use their dialect to call each other....

Comment: Hm, so nobody uses Mandarin for it, and that's why I can't find it?

Comment: There are some generalities like 婶 etc but I think you'll find it'll tend to change in different areas...which is why you can find it in Hokkien because its a dialect! : )